# wifi is not working in ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: wireless

Unable to disable Airplane mode. When i disable it, it switches back to the disable mode again. Also unable to switch ON wifi.

My laptop is hp pavilion-15 r007tx

[image]

$ lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
09:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
0a:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
0a:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
```

I install wifi driver Ralink RT3290 in my laptop and now the wifi is enable. [Wifi is Enabled, but not searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l02uI.png) 
But the only problem is that I am unable to search and connect to any hotspot.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the output of `lspci`.

Comment: Can you detach the ethernet cable, reboot and try it again?

Comment: i have already tried this, even several times while rebooting .

Answer (score -1):

You can try to install the wireless adapter driver.

In Ubuntu , you can install from **setting**-> **software&updates** -> **Additional divers**.

I hope it can help u~

Comment: This won't help. There are no Ralink drivers there.